# mysql_fetch_array returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i was creating some script , but mysql_fetch_array returns nothing the time i have data in my database .. mysql_error(); also returns no error but i don't know what's the problem here everything is right ..

```
if($_POST['submit'])
{
include("connect.php");
$query=mysql_query("select * from admins where id = '$userid'");
$fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$qs=$fetch['security_question'];
$an=$fetch['security_answer'];
   if($qs==$question)
   {
     if($an==$answer)
      {
      header("location:panel.php");
      }
   }
```

Comment: what is  $userid value ?

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly to see that data is returned?

Comment: @Darren : Yes and it works ..

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore cause they're deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead.

Comment: Are you sure your `connect.php` file have correct configuaration>

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER : Thanks i'll try it and tell you the result.

Comment: @Sadikhasan : Yes i'm already working with connect.php in other files and it's okay

Comment: check this `$_POST['submit']` exist. means echo some thing after this $_POST['submit'] condition.

Comment: @wild : i already did it and inputs values are printed normally .. but when i echo the fetch data nothing on the screen.

Comment: @user3787287 Can you echo your query like `echo "select * from admins where id = '$userid'"` what it prints?

Comment: @Sadikhasan Does this `echo "select * from admins where id = '$userid'"` sends any thing to the database ?? i just it's only a simple string for php ?

Comment: @user3787287 I mean echo your query and write that query in phpmyadmin and see what it return?

Comment: What is your userid attribute data type????

Comment: @Sadikhasan : already did it in the mysql command prompt and it returns true results.
@sam'solution : `$userid` is an integer ..

Comment: what you think guys of changing the line to `mysql_query("select * from admins where id ='1' and security_question='$question' and answer = '$answer' ");` ..
and then i check `mysql_num_rows`
 i think it'll be right .. no ?

Comment: i think there is something wrong with the tables .. i can fetch all the others .. but not those.

Comment: then look your table , or post your table schema .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that mysql_fetch_array return some value 
Means $userid maybe do not match with any userid in your database
Use mysql_num_rows to find how may row it return

Comment: The problem is that i tried with where `id = '1'` and this also didn't worked .. i don't know what's wrong `mysql_fetch_array` is working on the other pages normally ..

Comment: Use $_REQUEST I think problem in getting $userid value
You do not assign value to $userid variable

Comment: I tried using a static value for `$userid` but null result again

Answer (score 0):

You have to check following case.

1. Your Form data is Posted Proper or Not ?
2. Your database connection is all right ?
3. Have you got proper userid in $userid variable ?
4. You have to put static userid in place of $userid variable for testing purpose.
5. You have to check tableName spelling and connection file spelling is correct or not?

Might above case will help you to solve your problems.

Comment: Have you put static value in place of $userid varible?

Comment: Yeah i tested with '1' which is already in the database and nothing returned

Comment: I think your connection is not configured well.

Comment: Can you show your connection code and name of connection fileName?

Comment: i think there is something wrong with the tables .. i can fetch all the others .. but not those.

Comment: <?php
/********************************/
//DB CONFIGURATION//
$host="localhost"; //MYSQL SERVER
$user="root"; //MYSQL USER
$pass="ryshellpw"; //MYSQL PASS
$db="pausefilm"; //MYSQL DB NAME
/*******************************/
//MYSQL CONNECTION
$connection=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if(!$connection) 
{
echo "<font color=\"red\">Fatal server error: ".mysql_error()."</font>";
}
else
{
echo "ok";
}
//MYSQL CREATE & DB SELECT
$select_db=mysql_select_db($db);
if(!$select_db)
{
echo "<font color=\"red\">Fatal server error: ".mysql_error()."</font>";
}
/******************/
?>

Comment: Your connection is ok but Problem in `DB selection` Try to use `$select_db=mysql_select_db($db,$connection);` Instead of `$select_db=mysql_select_db($db);`

Comment: Sorry , but no problem in DB selection i'm working with at least 4 otherfiles including the same sql connection is good working .. and then the userid i get in first by fetching the database  here is steps 
1 - User enters Username and password 
2 - Check validity 
3 - Fetch user id 
4 - redirect to verification page with a get value `userid=the_fetched_user_id`

Comment: What is the name of `connection` file?

Comment: For select db check this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_select_db.asp